# Why is the if statement in Python Class not working in Driver?

Tags: python, class, if-statement

Whenever I run this class (included the applicable section of code):

```
def setLevel(self, level):
    if (self.__level == "Freshman" or self.__level == "Sophomore" or self.__level == "Junior" or self.__level == "Senior"):
        self.__level = level
    else:
        raise ValueError("Level must be Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, or Senior")
```

through this section of the driver class.

```
undergraduate = Undergraduate("Jonathan", "Zhang", "214-000-0000", Address("611 Leon", "Austin", "Texas", 78705), "234-56-7890", "student@utexas.edu", 2300106, "Management Information Systems", 3.95, "Loser")
```

I am allowed to use a string not included in the if statement. If I need to post anymore parts of the code, I can.

EDIT:

```
class Undergraduate(Student):

#Initializer
    def __init__(self, first_name='', last_name='', phone_number='', address=None, social_sec_num='', emailAddress='', major=0, desc='', gpa=0.0, level=''):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, phone_number, address, social_sec_num, emailAddress, major, desc, gpa)
        self.__level = level

#Mutator
    def setLevel(self, level):
        if (self.__level == "Freshman" or self.__level == "Sophomore" or self.__level == "Junior" or self.__level == "Senior"):
            self.__level = level
        else:
            raise ValueError("Level must be Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, or Senior")


#Accessor
    def getLevel(self):
        return self.__level

#String Representation
    def __str__(self):

        undergraduate_string = \
    "First Name: %s" %self.getFirstName() + "\n" +\
    "Last Name: %s" %self.getLastName() + "\n" +\
    "Phone Number: %s" %self.getPhoneNumber() + "\n" +\
    "Address: %s" %self.getAddress() + "\n" +\
    "Social Security Number: %s" %self.getSocialSecNum() + "\n" +\
    "Email Address: %s" %self.getEmailAddress() + "\n" +\
    "Major: %d" %self.getMajor() + "\n" +\
    "Description: %s" %self.getDesc() + "\n" +\
    "GPA: %.2f" %self.getGpa() + "\n" +\
    "Level: %s" %self.getLevel()

        return undergraduate_string
```

Comment: What's your question? I don't see one...

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33964098/edit) link on your question to add your class definition. Also you should take a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I thought it was implied. Why can the level string be 'loser' when the if statement says it must be 'freshman', 'sophomore', 'junior', or 'senior'.

Comment: what does the call to setLevel look like? I think we'd need to see more of the class

Comment: You need to post `Undergraduate.__init__` at the very least, but my blind guess would be that in the `if` statement you should be checking the value of `level` and not `self.__level`.

Comment: EDITED to include the full class.

Comment: Also consider using `if self.__level in ["Freshman", "Sophomore".,..]: ...`

Comment: again: what's the question?

Comment: Why do you think setLevel is being called?  ``__init__`` doesn't use it...

Comment: Double-underscores have a special meaning in python - consider renaming `__level` to `_level` if you were intending to mark it as a private variable.

Comment: You've shown us where you initialize `Undergraduate(...)` but you haven't shown any calls to `setLevel()` where the `if` clause lurks. You need to call `setLevel` to hit the if. As an aside, its kinda strange to verify `self.__level` instead of `level` in that bit of code.

Comment: @Seth, `__level` _is_ the python "private" variable syntax. I don't see how removing a `_` will help OP here.

Comment: @tdelaney I was speculating that `__level` may have been defined in the superclass, which would cause problems for `Undergraduate()`. Also, my "were" should have been "weren't"